# Force telnet / ssh to use crtl-H for backspace

Tags: linux, terminal, terminal-emulator, telnet, rxvt

I have some devices connected to a Cisco serial term server; many work fine when I `telnet` directly to the port on the Cisco.  However, I have a few stubborn devices that will not use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> as it is mapped in telnet by default.

In case it matters, I telnet from `rxvt` under Debian squeeze (in an X Window).  `TERM` is set to `rxvt`, but it doesn't matter whether I use `vt100`, `vt101`, or `xterm`... changing `TERM` has no effect.  I started down the road of changing `TERM` based on what I saw in an [old Kermit FAQ](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/backspace.html).  FWIW, `stty erase ^h` and `stty erase ^?` don't work either.

I have noticed that <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works correctly on these devices if I use a raw TCP socket from `netcat`... i.e. `nc 192.168.12.117 2006`; however, then I run into other issues with passwords not hidden or terminal paging.

How can I selectively force telnet and ssh to map <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> for these devices?  Also, what criteria should I use to evaluate whether this is a bug in the device?

### EDIT

In case it matters, this is the output from `showkey -a` for the keys in question... `^?` corresponds to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and `^H` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.  It seems like I should be getting close when I look at [The Linux Keyboard and Console Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html), but I can't seem to decipher what I can do to change this.  I have tried various incantations with `loadkeys` to no effect.

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee docs]$ sudo showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^?      127 0177 0x7f
^H        8 0010 0x08
```

I am also including relevant output from `dumpkeys` as well... this is the current mapping in my system (which doesn't work on some devices in question).  If I could figure out how to get <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to do the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, I would have a solution.

```
[mpenning@hotcoffee docs]$ sudo dumpkeys | grep -Ei "backspace|127"
keycode   8 = BackSpace        ampersand        braceleft       
keycode  14 = BackSpace        Delete          
        control keycode  14 = BackSpace       
keycode 127 =
[mpenning@hotcoffee docs]$
```

Comment: Have you tried `ssty erase '^?'`? If the devices insist on a `C-h`, it's not telnet's call, it's the terminal (emulator)'s.

Comment: @Gilles your comment is actually not correct, see my answer below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found an answer in [Anne Baretta's Linux Keyboard Hall of Shame](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html)... it seems that **changing key mappings in `xterm` / `rxvt` does no good for `telnet`**.

I validated this when I sniffed the telnet connection.  First I sniffed the telnet session and saw that <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sent `0x7f` to the host. Next I intentionally broke <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in `rxvt` using `stty erase $` (thus mapping my Backspace to the dollar sign in `rxvt`).    After doing this, I had to hit <kbd>$</kbd> to backspace in `rxvt`, but `telnet` still sent `0x7f` when I used <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on the remote host.

### SOLUTION

Create a script called `kbdfix` (below), and make it executable with `755` permissions; you will need the `tclsh` and `expect` packages loaded from your distribution archives.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#Name this file as kbdfix and make it executable in your path
eval spawn -noecho $argv

interact {
 \177        {send "\010"}
 "\033\[3~"  {send "\177"}
}
```

Now to connect to the broken hosts, I type `kbdfix telnet 192.168.12.117 2006`, and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works.

Note for anyone confused by 2006 above... that is the TCP port that the Cisco term server uses for the serial connection to the console of the broken device (in this case, a Brocade FCX switch).

If you are merely telnetting to a device that doesn't like <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, you would use `kbdfix telnet <addr_of_the_broken_device>`.  I am also using this with ssh when I ssh to a DLink DGS-3200 Ethernet switch that has similar issues; the syntax is `kbdfix ssh 172.16.1.26`.

Comment: `stty erase $` doesn't map the "backspace" key to "$", it tells the tty driver that in order to erase a character, the "$" key need to be used. When you run telnet, you are in raw mode so this setting is ignored. A simple solution would be to configure your terminal emulator to send ^H for backspace, as god intended, another one is using your hack which translates these character on the fly using expect.

Comment: @jlliagre, yes, I discovered how `stty` did not change `telnet`'s keyboard reads when I used `wireshark`; however, this important fact was not clear to me until I sniffed.  I will investigate how I can change Backspace to use `Control_h` in `rxvt`... or maybe I need to think about finding another term.

Comment: @Mike: I think you're still confused about something (which I admit neither jlliagre nor I mentioned explicitly; I've updated my answer). `stty` needs to run on the application side. I highly doubt `telnet` is translating input characters or that you need to use `script`; just running `stty` on the remote machine will probably do the trick.

Comment: @Gilles, the remote machine is a network device, it does not have `stty`.

Comment: @Mike: Oh, I see. Then your issue isn't with telnet (it's just the messenger), it's with the remote device. (Your blaming telnet is what was confusing me, and I think jlliagre.) Then using some intermediate software that performs the translation, such as expect or screen, is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @Gilles, the reason I was trying to modify telnet's behavior is because it seemed like telnet was causing a difference in this particular case.  netcat was not having an issue with backspace (which is something I will track down when I have some spare moments).  I need to figure out whether the device (a Brocade switch) has a bug, or this is simply a nasty "feature"

Comment: @Mike: When you use netcat, your terminal is in cooked mode: you write a line, editing it *locally*, and `Enter` sends it. When you use telnet, your terminal is in raw mode: each character is sent immediately to the application. See e.g. the beginning of [this page](http://www.lafn.org/~dave/linux/terminalIO.html), or [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Early_Unices:_Seventh_Edition_Unix).

Answer (score 4):

Programs are supposed to query the terminal settings to find out what the backspace character is (`^h` and `^?`, i.e. `\010` and `\177`, are the two choices out there). Use `stty erase '^h'` or `stty erase '^?'` to declare what your terminal sends.

If you log in remotely (with telnet, rsh or ssh) inside the terminal, note that you must run `stty` **on the application side**. `stty` doesn't tell the terminal to do anything different, it informs the local terminal driver (i.e. the part that interfaces with applications running in the terminal) about the terminal (historically a physical object, now a terminal emulator) settings. Similarly, if you run Screen or similar terminal-in-terminal software, you need to run `stty` in each screen window (but usually Screen can be configured to do the right thing from its configuration file, if it doesn't work out of the box).

The difference in behavior that you observe from `netcat` vs. `telnet` is due to the way the terminal is used:
* In netcat, the terminal is in line-by-line mode (also called “cooked mode”). You edit a line (using the local terminal's built-in edition feature, and so in particular the local stty settings), then send it in its final state to the remote host.
* In telnet, the (local) terminal is in character-by-character mode (also called “raw mode”). Every keystroke goes directly to telnet which relays it immediately to the remote system. You are dependent on the remote system's line edition features.

There are broken programs out there that don't care about the terminal settings. Looks like you've encountered one of them. Your best bet is to change your terminal's configuration. The same goes if you need to communicate with a device over a remote protocol such as telnet or SSH and the device is not configurable.

With xterm, it's easy: there's a setting to toggle the character sent by the <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> key at run-time. From the left button menu, toggle “Delete is DEL”. Programmatically, send the [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) `\e[?67h` to have <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> send `^h`, or `\e[?67l` to have <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> send `^?`. The corresponding resource is `XTerm.backarrowKeyIsErase`. Other terminal emulators may or may not have a similar interface feature or support the escape sequence.

Many terminal emulators send one of `^h` or `^?` when you press <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, and the other character when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>. This can be useful in a pinch.

Note that `showkeys` and friends are only relevant on the Linux console, not within X.

Answer (score 3):

Backspace and Control-H were designed to be the same thing but nowadays, especially on Linux, you often have backspace sending delete and delete sending some odd escape sequence.

In any case and as far as I know, telnet or the TERM variable shouldn't change what backspace sends, this is usually a terminal emulator configuration feature.

Comment: Your question is based on the assumption telnet is doing specific processing of the backspace key which I believe is wrong. I should have put that as a comment instead of an answer indeed.

Comment: AFAICT, `telnet` pays no attention to local terminal mappings of the keyboard.  [Anne Barreta's notes about the keyboard and telnet](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html#other)

Comment: I'm afraid you are misunderstanding what stty does.